# JFrame title bar overlapping graphics

Tags: java, swing, jframe, layout-manager

i was following the David Brackeen's Developing Games in Java book and i made a simple script that allows to enter windowed mode. Well .. the problem is that when i draw the buttons the title bar overlaps them . Is there a way to fix it ?

ScreenShot:

[image]
See it? The bar overlaps the buttons!

Here is the netbeans project (the main source file is MenuTest): http://www.mediafire.com/?tyc16am8ga517c7

Comment: What is the layout you use? Maybe the widgets don't reposition correctly.

Comment: nobody knows what did you tried, nor which part of `David Brackeen's Developing Games in Java Book`, edit yu post with a http://sscce.org/ that demonstrated your issues

Comment: :D i dont use any layout :) , i mean i just swiched the deafult fullscreen mode to windowed mode and this happend :/ i thought of  expanding the window and then moving the graphics down

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) use proper [LayoutManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) instead of `setSize` / `setBounds`

2) use `paintComponent()` for Swing JComponents instead of `paint()` method

3) use [KeyBindinds](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) rather than [KeyListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html)

Comment: Thanks :) , i was rather thinking of expnding the window then moving graphics down , but those solutions are also ok .